# Как получить данные с сайта через Аndroid?

Tags: android, java

Добрый день.

Подскажите, есть вэб-сервер со страницей с данными в виде массива с параметрами. Как через андроид обратится к вэб-серверу и вытянуть определенное значение массива? Не могу понять, каким методом и классом воспользоваться. Если можно с примером.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

В любом случае Вам нужен [httpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html), а потом парсить данные. Но как именно - это сильно зависит от сайта и того, как там эти данные представлены. Может быть, они там на картинке нарисованы. :) Ссылку было бы неплохо предоставить.

Comment: Вот такой массив по ссылке. Мне нужно вытащить значение параметра `[REMOTE_PORT]`:


    Array ( [REMOTE_PORT] => 52798 [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1 [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.0 [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET [QUERY_STRING] => [REQUEST_URI] => /message.php [SCRIPT_NAME] => /messaget.php [PHP_SELF] => /messaget.php [REQUEST_TIME] => 9999999 )

Comment: Пусть сервер отдает данные в json формате ─ будет удобнее.

Comment: "Пусть сервер отдает данные в json формате ─ будет удобнее."

Не могу на это повлиять, к сожаленю.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь всё зависит по большей части от самого сервера. Как я понял, он на GET запрос в index возвращает HTML с данными. Это непрактично и неудобно. Обычно, при запросе данных через GET  и POST запросы в формате JSON, который уже легко парсится. Но судя по предыдущим комментариям, вы повлиять на сам сервер не можете. Тогда, для парсинга HTML могу предложить библиотеку jsoup.